# Error join in codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

My join not working! i have this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Call to a member function ris_array() on a non-object in
/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/****/application/views/exam/add_view.php on line 90.
```

In add_view:

```
<table border="0">
  <tr>    
    <th>ID_patient</th>    
    <th>ID_visit</th>
  </tr>

  <?php
    foreach ($query->ris_array() as $row){  
      echo $row['id_pat'];  
      echo $row['id_visit'];  
    }
  ?>
</table>
```

join (table visit and in patient (id_visit join id_pat)) controller:

```
public function join($id_pat){
  $this->load->model('visit_model');
  $data['info'] = $this->mods->joins();
  $this->load->view('add_view', $data);
}
```

in visit model:

```
function joins(){
  $this->db->select('*');
  $this->db->from('patient');
  $this->db->join('visit', 'visit.id_visit = patient.id_pat');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->ris_array();
}
```

Comment: never heard of `return $query->ris_array();` till date you can use `result_array()` or `result()`

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your model:

```
function joins()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('patient');
    $this->db->join('visit', 'visit.id_visit = patient.id_pat');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query;
}
```

In your controller:

```
public function join($id_pat)
{
    $this->load->model('visit_model');
    $data['visits'] = $this->visit_model->joins();
    $this->load->view('add_view', $data);
}
```

Then in your view:

```
<table border="0">
<tr>    

      <th>ID_patient</th>    

      <th>ID_visit</th>
</tr>
<?php foreach ($query as $row) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?= $row->id_pat ?></td>
    <td><?= $row->id_visit ?></td>
</tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Error log: Message: Undefined variable: query
Filename: visit/add_view.php and Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Answer (score 0):

Change this :

```
 return $query->ris_array();
```

To :

```
return $query->result_array();
```